# How Does Windows Live Sync Beta Allow for Microsoft Office Sharing?

Tags: c#, windows, live, synchronization

In the new [Windows Live Sync Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/d9f1663c-764f-4556-96a8-62379b2175cd) you can sync your program settings, though it's restricted to Internet Explorer and Microsoft Office only right now. How do I access this functionality in C# so that my apps will also support this? Is it just a custom folder that's auto-added? I figure they MUST be using some public APIs.